# How to Combine data with same element in Angular in a tree structure

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular project where I need to **show data in tree structure**[ Parent child form]
API has **JSON data where Label,dd1,dd2 these three elements** are present.

```
{
        "label": "Medium",
        "id": 12705,
        "dd1": "Cat A",
        "dd1id": 40875,
        "dd2": "Non Cision",
        "dd2id": 50960
    },
{
        "label": "Medium",
        "labelid": 12705,
        "dd1": "Cat A",
        "dd1id": 40876,
        "dd2": null,
        "dd2id": null 
    }
```

I am **facing two major issues** while showing data in UI -

1. Many Labels value are same in JSON data so whenever Label value is same all the children under label should be under 1 parent like above JSON you can see label is same so it should come under one parent which is label, children of both same labels ->dd1,dd2 should come under 1 parent but it is not working see in below image.
2. I am trying to show Label as a parent and dd1 as a child under Label and  dd2 as a child if it has data and dd1 as parent of dd2, `Label(Parent) -> dd1 (child/ make dd1 parent for dd2 if value present) ->dd2 (child if value is present if null hide it)` but it is not happening.

I am using Mat-tree to show tree structure -

TS Code-

```
getQualifyParams() {
 var perm = {
     id: "133",
     username: "John",
};
 this.article.qualifyTheArticle(perm).subscribe(
(res) => {
    let value = res.result;

  value.forEach((val) => {
     val.name = val.label;
     val.id = val.labelid;
     val.children = [{ name: val.dd1, id: val.dd1id }];
});
     this.dataSource.data = value;
         },
(err) => {
         console.log(err);
   }
 ); 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really I don't know if you want

```
data.map((x) => ({
  label: x.label,
  id: x.id,
  children: [
    {
      id: x.dd1id,
      label: x.dd1,
      children: x.dd2 ? [
            {
              id: x.dd2id,
              label: x.dd2,
            },
          ]: null,
    },
  ],
}));
```

or

```
data.map((x) => ({
  label: x.label,
  id: x.id,
  children: x.dd2id ? [
        {
          id: x.dd1id,
          label: x.dd1,
        },
        {
          id: x.dd2id,
          label: x.dd2,
        },
      ]: [
        {
          id: x.dd1id,
          label: x.dd1,
        },
      ],
}));
```

**Update** If we want to join the "children" is a bit complex.

This code check if "id" are equals -not the "label"- I put in comments to try explain it

```
data.reduce((a: any, b: any) => {
  //in bb we has an object of type 
  // {id:..,label:...,children:[
  //      id:...,label:...,children:[..]
  //      ]}
  const bb = {
    label: b.label,
    id: b.id,
    children: [
      {
        id: b.dd1id,
        label: b.dd1,
        children: b.dd2
          ? [
              {
                id: b.dd2id,
                label: b.dd2,
              },
            ]
          : null,
      },
    ],
  };
  //search in "a" if we has an element with the same "id"
  const element = a.find((x) => x.id == bb.id);

  //if not found simply "concat" the element to the array a 
  if (!element) return [...a, bb];

  //concat the children of the element found and the new element
  const children = [...(element.children || []), ...(bb.children || [])]

  //we want to make some like above with the "children"
  const child=children.reduce(
    (c: any, d: any) => {

      //search in "c" if we has an element with the same "id"
      const elementZ = c.find((x:any) => x.id == d.id);

      //if not found simply "concat" the element to the array c 
      if (!elementZ) return [...c, d];

      //if found concat the children, only not repeat elements
      elementZ.children = [...(elementZ.children || []), ...(d.children || [])]
      .reduce((e:any,f:any)=>e.find(x=>x.id==f.id)?e:[...e,f],[]);

      return c
    },
    []
  );
  element.children = child;
  return a;
}, []);
```

see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gethdv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts)

It's looks like very complex (there' a lot of reduce). To explain a reduce to get unique values we can think in a simple loop

```
data.reduce((a,b)=>{
  if (!a.find(x=>x.id==b.id)){
     ..we make "something" with a usign values of b...
     return a
  }
  return [...a,b])
},[])
```

we can "translate" like

```
   a=[];
   data.forEach(x=>{
      if (!a.find(x=>x.id==b.id)){
         ..we make "something" with a usign values of b...
         return a
      }
      return [...a,b])
   })
```

Comment: Neither of them is working, if label are same in all data then its value should be combine under one label like `{label:a,dd1:abc},{label:b,dd1:bcd},{label:a,dd1:xyz}` in this condition *value with label a are two abc and xyz so it should come under one parent and abc,xyz as a child for a, a->abc,xyz*

Comment: @archana, I update the answer. Really is a bit complex, don't worry if you don't understand at first, read it carefully. I write severals comments I hope can help you